# Inserir imagem junto com texto na mesma coluna do tipo blob

Tags: php, mysqli

Tem como inserir imagem e texto na mesma coluna e mostrar na mesma ordem que foi inserido por exemplo:

inserindo

1->[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui] 2->Texto

visualizando

1->[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui] 2->Texto

Comment: 1) sim tem como, 2) usa algum framework css?, 3)Basta vc colocar em "ordem" a exibição dessas informações, 4) Pensa em como ficaria a estrutura do HTML e depois aplica "dinamicamente" com PHP

Comment: ter como, tem, mas não vejo a necessidade de complicar as coisas assim